# Call custom function from within Pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I would like to write a Pytest fixture in `conftest.py` that, within itself, calls a function that, by default, does nothing but can be redefined in test modules.

```
#conftest.py

def within_foo():
    pass

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    if some_condition():
        within_foo()
    something_else()


# test_foo.py

def within_foo():
    print('this should be printed when running test_foo')

def test_foo(foo):
    pass
```

Is there a clean way to implement this?

Comment: Who will test your tests? Seems complicated.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Are you asking who is going write the tests? The writing of tests will be done by several software engineers, which is why I am concerned with making it as intuitive and light on overhead as possible.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not answering your specific question. But it's matter of your context of your actual constraints. I ask, is it prudent to have complicated logic in tests? Your app has complicated logic, to validate it you write tests. If your tests have complicated logic you will have to write tests on tests.

Comment: @mrEvgenX I see what you mean. We are translating from a deprecated testing framework to Pytest and while this will bring multiple plusses, we have the hard constraint that writing tests will "feel" the same to the engineers.  In the end, the logic will not be too complex. We just have to inject some code between some steps of the test setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with inheritance. Create a base class for all tests, than you can decide in which tests you want to override `within_foo()`

```
class BaseTest:

    @pytest.fixture
    def foo(self):
        self.within_foo()

    def within_foo(self):
        pass

@pytest.mark.testing
class TestSomething(BaseTest):

    def within_foo(self):
        print('this should be printed when running test_foo')

    def test_foo(self, foo):
        pass

@pytest.mark.testing
class TestSomethingElse(BaseTest):

    def test_foo_again(self, foo):
        print('test_foo_again')
```

Outout

```
========================== 2 passed in 0.08 seconds ===========================
this should be printed when running test_foo
.test_foo

.test_foo_again
```